# Why does the result differ from the original, after baking hair?

Tags: particles

When I bake a hair particle simulation, the hair becomes strange and detached from the emitter mesh; what did I do wrong?

Original:

[image]

After Bake:

[image]

I used the default hair dynamic settings, but also tried to fiddle with hair weight and still get the same result. If relevant, I am using Blender 2.74

[image]

Comment: Is the particle modifier after any mesh deforming modifiers? like armature?

Comment: i dont think so, i do parent the hair emitter mesh to my character armature (head bone). but i dont see any modifier beside particle system on it. @sambler